# Blur filter for IE 10+

Tags: internet-explorer, css, filter

I need to make a blur effect on a div. I know that for Chrome I can use CSS3 filters and for IE and Firefox I have to use an SVG filter. What I cannot figure out is why my SVG filter will not work in IE 10+ but works fine in Firefox?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8pytt/3/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <filter id="blur">
       <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
   </filter>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
body {
        background: blue;
    }

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
    opacity: .8;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, white, black);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, white, black);
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, white, black);
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, white, black);

    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter:url('#blur');
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

IE still (on 11 now) doesn't support `filter:blur()`. IE10 supports SVG filters, but not for non-SVG content. I would just say you could use a `foreignObject` and change the opacity to rgba opacity, [**like this**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/8pytt/11/), but it turns out IE doesn't support `foreignObject` either.

So either you can convert it all to SVG or fallback to an opacity change or something. [**See here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx) and the [**linked page**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/10/14/svg-filter-effects-in-ie10.aspx) for more info.

Even in Edge, CSS filter effects require users to [allow a custom flag](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters) and don't support the `url()` functionality.

Comment: Knowing that, can you think of a way to make this work still? I haven't been able to find a polyfill for IE 10 +.

Comment: @Gho5t I updated my answer, but I'm afraid there is no work around at the moment