# CSS Filter - Blur

Tags: html, css, svg

I am using this example from [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/jonitrythall/pen/GJQBOp)

To re-create the same Frosted-Glass like effect on my navigation bar. The problem is, it works in Chrome/Firefox, but not in Edge/IE...

i have tried using:

```
-ms-filter: blur(3px)
filter: blur(3px)
```

As well as an SVG Filter, like so:

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf9,
             <svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                 <filter id='blur'>
                     <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3'/>
                 </filter>
             </svg>#blur");
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
```

But none of this seems to give me the desired result.
Even the CodePen example does not work in Edge/IE.
Is there a way around this issue?

Comment: I guess it's not you(your code) it's the browser.

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969853/blur-filter-for-ie-10